# Excel Average Delivery Time ETA Timestamp

Tags: excel, timestamp, average

First full disclosure. Excel is new to me. My boss has given me this task. I've tried to search yadda yadda here I am. :)

I have been given the task over SETTING a NEW ETA for milk DELIVERIES. So I've taken all 700 STOPS in our region and COPY and PASTED ARRIVAL TIMES from every STOP over the LAST 50 DAYS.

I am trying to AVERAGE ETA.

Example: Truck arrives between 11:37 pm and 1:30 am over the last 50 days.

Solution:
I have 50 exact delivery times and I need an average time that falls in the 11:37 pm to 1:30 am window.

What I've tried.

AutoSum AVERAGE gives a time of 4:30 pm.
Converting all times to decimals.
Formating Custom and choosing [h]:mm:ss

The only way I seem to get a time anywhere near a valuable ETA is to change to military time and change 0:15 to 24:15, 1:15 to 25:15 etc.

While I could manually enter this in 23,000 cells there has to be an easier way.

HELP! =)

[Picture of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pweJo.jpg)

Comment: Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The fact that you didn't bother to complete the 2-minute site tour looks bad.  Let's see a screenshot snippet of your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screen shot]

I took a shot at this. As you can see, I formatted columns B2, C2 as time hh:mm:ss AM/PM then I simply used AVERAGE formula in D2 as AVERAGE of B2 and C2
Excel seems to be doing the right thing here and I even used multiple columns 
and experimented with some times.
Perhaps all that is needed is to format the cells so that the format represents as time AM/PM.